# Force full object load with eager loading and nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My object model goes a little something like this:

```
Order
    has_many line items
    has_many transactions
    has_many products through line items
Line Items
    has_one product
```

So, to get all of the orders for a product I've been going:

```
product = Product.find(1)
Order.includes(:transactions, line_items: [:product]).where(line_items: {product: product})
```

The issue here is that if an order has 5 line items, I want all 5 line items loaded when I'm looking at the order object. However, using the code above I'm only getting the line item with the specified product. Is there a way to fully load the order object, without going .reload individually on each item? Just want to eager load the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be difficult to do in only one query. The most straightforward I could get using just ActiveRecord methods was this:

```
Order.includes(:transactions, line_items: [:product])
     .where(id: LineItem.where(product: product).pluck(:order_id))
```

I don't know much about Arel, but I think it might be able to accomplish this in one query rather than two.

Comment: This works! The best way I've seen to do this so far. Thank you :)